# NamedPipe with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a namedpipe between a console application and a asp.net-app. When i try to send something from the asp.net page to the console it works perfektly.. but not otherwise.

Codebehind (asp):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TESTASP
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        NamedPipeClient nc;
        NamedPipeServer ns;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nc = new NamedPipeClient("myNamedPipe1");
            ns = new NamedPipeServer("myNamedPipe2");
            nc.ClientListen();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ns.newstring += new NewString(np_newstring);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ns.ServerListen));
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        void np_newstring(string text)
        {
           this.Session["string"] = text;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nc.Write("test");
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = (string)Session["string"];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is at line:

```
this.Session["string"] = text;
```

When i debug the project, there is a value in "text" but it says:

(translated with google translate...)

> Session state can only be used if set enableSessionState either in a
>   configuration file or in the page directive to "true". Also make sure
>   that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module in
>   the application configuration in  \  \
>    section is included.

The NamedPipeServer-class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TESTASP
{
    public class NamedPipeServer
    {
        static FileStream fStream;
        private const uint DUPLEX = (0x00000003);
        private const uint FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = (0x40000000);

        private string PIPE_NAME = "\\\\.\\pipe\\myNamedPipe";
        private const uint BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        public event NewString newstring;

        public NamedPipeServer(string name)
        {
            PIPE_NAME = "\\\\.\\pipe\\" + name;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateNamedPipe(
           String pipeName,
           uint dwOpenMode,
           uint dwPipeMode,
           uint nMaxInstances,
           uint nOutBufferSize,
           uint nInBufferSize,
           uint nDefaultTimeOut,
           IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int ConnectNamedPipe(
           SafeFileHandle hNamedPipe,
           IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        public void ServerListen()
        {

            SafeFileHandle clientPipeHandle;
            while (true)
            {
                clientPipeHandle = CreateNamedPipe(
                   PIPE_NAME,
                   DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                   0,
                   255,
                   BUFFER_SIZE,
                   BUFFER_SIZE,
                   0,
                   IntPtr.Zero);

                //failed to create named pipe
                if (clientPipeHandle.IsInvalid)
                    break;

                int success = ConnectNamedPipe(
                   clientPipeHandle,
                   IntPtr.Zero);

                //failed to connect client pipe
                if (success != 1)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    fStream = new FileStream(clientPipeHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 4096, true);
                    string test = Read();
                    if (!test.Equals("###"))
                        newstring(test);
                }
            }

        }

        private string Read()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

                //could not read from file stream
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    return "###";


                return encoder.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');
            }
        }

        public void Write(string message)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] sendBuffer = encoder.GetBytes(message);
            fStream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
            fStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Web.Config:

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </httpModules>

    <pages enableSessionState="true"/>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>



  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

I hope you can help me :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You start a thread within a page request to receive data from a pipe. When you call this page the thread will be started but the request is probably terminated before the answer comes from the pipe and you cannot write into the session data anymore.

You only get access to the Session within the current webcontext.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

This will be null if called from an outside thread.

Comment: hmm.. is there no way to put the received data into a session?

application example: my console does something and sends the percentage-value through the pipe. i want to see the percentage in the asp-page (through a ajax timer)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can you not call a service from the web applicaton into the console app to receive the value?

Comment: Never tried it with webservices before.
I think it's time to try it ;)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a web service. You probably can use your existing pipe service and receive the result by calling the console app instead of a call from the console app into the web app. Good luck ;-)